# jQuery Plugin: Limiting script tag references to other libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am about to create a jQuery plugin but I was thinking of using a few other libraries. Now for it to be easy to use I was wondering if there are ways to limited the amount of script tag references I have to add.

Few options I was considering:

1: Include the library code into the plugin code. Not sure if this is viable? It will increase the size of the plugin.

2: I just read about google.loader so I don't know a lot about it yet. Seems like a way you can load libraries from inside your code using Google API. It does require an API key though so this might not be for everybody.

So StackOverflow, how do you deal with this problem?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't include the library code in the plugin, it not only makes the plugin fatter, but unmaintainable over time.

Why are you reluctant to limit the amount of script tag references?

Comment: I guess it mostly is about making it easier to use and be a bit more portable. I want to maybe use jQuery UI, jQuery.tmpl and json2.js so that's at least 3 extra references people will need to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't include other libraries from inside the plugin, nobody wants to use a plugin that has hidden includes to external libraries that could possibly break the main program.

If you are looking for a way to include scripts without manually adding script tags, you can try the jQuery.loadScript or any equivalent methods from closure/google or YUI.

Here is another simple method I used once that works pretty well:

```
function loadScript( url, callback ) {
    var done = false,
        script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;

   // Attach handlers for all browsers
   script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if ( !done && (!this.readyState ||
           this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') ) {
           done = true;

           if (typeof callback == 'function') {
               callback.call( window, script );
           }

           // Handle memory leak in IE
           script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
       }
   };

   var s = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' )[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore( script, s );
};
```